# How to change Provided dependencies when using Intellij with SBT?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt-assembly

My build.sbt looks like this:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value % Provided
)
```

While running my application from Intellij, I get `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions because it cannot find spark libraries. So when using Intellij, I need:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value % Provided
)
```

But that causes the final flat jar to be very big.

How to have different list of Provided dependencies depending whether using Intellij or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803413/1020190 may help.

Comment: What do you mean by "running your app in IntelliJ"? Unit test?

Comment: In my use case, this is a Spark job meant to run under EMR which already provides these dependencies in the classpath. During development time, I use Intellij and those dependencies are missing. I'd like to have single build.sbt which address this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for my use case was to check IntelliJ `Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath` option. Found it here:
[How to work efficiently with SBT, Spark and "provided" dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437814/how-to-work-efficiently-with-sbt-spark-and-provided-dependencies)

Since UI has changed, here are the screenshots for Intellij 2021.2.3:

[image]

After selecting it, you should see:
[image]