# sbt assembly switch between provided dependencies

Tags: java, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am developing a spark application. To test it locally I want to run `sbt` run. This requires the dependencies to be available locally. But I also want to use `sbt assembly` to generate a jar which can be used for `spark-submit` that jar should only include some of the dependencies e.g. not include the spark dependencies.

When I mark a dependency in `build.sbt` as `% "provided"` it no longer is available via `sbt run`

Comment: This question has 2 subquestions - you should split it to two separate questions to make it easier to answer

Comment: ok I wil do that. Here is question 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782435/sbt-switch-dependencies-for-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the case to exclude jars in assembly use in main built.sbt

```
excludedJars in assembly := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter {f =>
     f.data.getName.contains("spark"),
     f.data.getName.startsWith("jar_name")
  }
}
```

Comment: but still this does not exclude transitive dependencies for spark e.g. I am facing problems with kryo .. how can I exclude all "transitive" dependencies of a jar as well?

Comment: I want to add http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838944/how-to-add-provided-dependencies-back-to-run-test-tasks-classpath/21803413#21803413 is a nicer solution for my specific usecase with spark.