# Understanding build.sbt with sbt-spark-package plugin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-graphx, sbt-plugin

I am new the scala and SBT build files. From the introductory tutorials adding spark dependencies to a scala project should be straight-forward via the sbt-spark-package plugin but I am getting the following error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkContext
```

Please provide resources to learn more about what could be driving error as I want to understand process more thoroughly.

CODE:

```scala
trait SparkSessionWrapper {

  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("spark citation graph")
      .getOrCreate()
  }

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

}


import org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader

object Test extends SparkSessionWrapper {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Testing, testing, testing, testing...")

    var filePath = "Desktop/citations.txt"
    val citeGraph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, filepath)
    println(citeGraph.vertices.take(1))
  }
}
```

plugins.sbt

```scala
resolvers += "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"

addSbtPlugin("org.spark-packages" % "sbt-spark-package" % "0.2.6")
```

build.sbt -- WORKING. Why does libraryDependencies run/work ?

```scala
spName := "yewno/citation_graph"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

sparkVersion := "2.2.0"

sparkComponents ++= Seq("core", "sql", "graphx")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "2.2.0"
)
```

build.sbt -- NOT WORKING. Would expect this to compile & run correctly

```scala
spName := "yewno/citation_graph"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

sparkVersion := "2.2.0"

sparkComponents ++= Seq("core", "sql", "graphx")
```

Bonus for explanation + links to resources to learn more about SBT build process, jar files, and anything else that can help me get up to speed!

Answer (score 2):

[sbt-spark-package plugin](https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package/blob/a8fd991f9b68e1961b997ee11c3516eb714cbd69/src/main/scala/sbtsparkpackage/SparkPackagePlugin.scala#L297) provides dependencies in `provided` scope:

```
sparkComponentSet.map { component =>
  "org.apache.spark" %% s"spark-$component" % sparkVersion.value % "provided"
}.toSeq
```

We can confirm this by running `show libraryDependencies` from sbt:

```
[info] * org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12
[info] * org.apache.spark:spark-core:2.2.0:provided
[info] * org.apache.spark:spark-sql:2.2.0:provided
[info] * org.apache.spark:spark-graphx:2.2.0:provided
```

[`provided`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#-provided-configuration) scope means:

> The dependency will be part of compilation and test, but excluded from
>   the runtime.

Thus `sbt run` throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkContext`

If we really want to include `provided` dependencies on `run` classpath then [@douglaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838944/how-to-add-provided-dependencies-back-to-run-test-tasks-classpath/21803413#21803413) suggests:

```
run in Compile := Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in (Compile, run), runner in (Compile, run)).evaluated
```

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you. So for someone new to developing Scala projects what would be your suggestion for handling the tasks of running code (basic module tests) vs shipping final projects? Like is it "good practice" to leave douglaz's one-liner in the build file?