# How to force adding provided dependency to fat jar using sbt-assembly plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a Spark project which I usually package with sbt-assembly. All spark dependencies are marked `provided` and not included in my fat jar.
I want to have another command to build a really fat jar with all dependencies, spark included.
I am trying the following with no luck:

```
lazy val standalone = project
.dependsOn(mainProj % "compile->compile;test->test;provided->compile")
.settings(
  logLevel in assembly := Level.Debug,
  assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = true, includeDependency = true)
)
```

Note, the answers to [How to add "provided" dependencies back to run/test tasks' classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18838944/5205022) explain how to add `provided` dependencies to the runtime classpath, however my question is about how to have them end up in the packaged artifact after executing `sbt assembly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a truly fat jar which packages everything including `provided` dependencies, we could redefine [`fullClasspath in assembly`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/4a211b329bf31d9d5f0fae67ea4252896d8a4a4d/src/main/scala/sbtassembly/AssemblyPlugin.scala#L131) like so

```
assembly / fullClasspath := (Compile / fullClasspath).value
```

If we put this in a separate command like so

```
commands += Command.command("assemblyTrulyFatJar") { state =>
  """set assembly / fullClasspath := (Compile / fullClasspath).value""" :: "assembly" :: state
}
```

then executing `sbt assemblyTrulyFatJar` should package everything, while `sbt assembly` keeps its default behaviour.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it only allows me to run the app in the IDE, which is not what I want. 
Instead I want to be able to have a command similar to "sbt assembly" which will package everything, including provided deps

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding the question. Please see edited answer which consists of defining `assembly / fullClasspath := (Compile / fullClasspath).value`. I will also ask the moderators to hopefully get the `duplicated` mark removed.